# How to make IAuthorization policy in ASP .NET Core without requirement

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to add my custom database logic in my application by making a new policy.

The problem is that when I override `HandleAsync` method in `IAuthorizationHandler` interface, I don't have the option to call `context.Succeed();` without passsing a requirement.

Is this a good idea to do in my first IF clause to put all my pending requirements as succeeded and am I going to override the behavior of my other policy "ApiScope" and create a problem?

Here is my implementation of IAthorizationHandler and I also have custom class IAuthenticationService

```
public class GroupsValidationHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory;

    public GroupsValidationHandler(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        this.serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var authService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationService>();
            var userGroups = context.User.FindAll("groups").Select(X => X.Value).ToList();
            var result = await authService.AllGroupsExist(userGroups);

            var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();

            if (result)
            {
                foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
                var filterContext = context.Resource as DefaultHttpContext;
                var response = filterContext?.HttpContext.Response;
                response?.OnStarting(async () =>
                {
                    if (filterContext != null)
                    {
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I have in `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, GroupsValidationHandler>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "customScope");
    });
    options.AddPolicy("ValidateGroups", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
    options.InvokeHandlersAfterFailure = false;
});

app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization("ApiScope", "ValidateGroups");
```

Comment: The Authorization policy is based on requirement,It make no sense to configure a policy without requirement ,and your handler indicates it's handling mutipule requirement:If the ticket contains a claim type of "scope" and has the value of "customScope",the context would mark all the requirements have been met with the codes:context.Succeed(requirement)

Answer (score 0):

I still need to check manually for other policies/claims I require but found this working for my case

```
if (context.User.Claims.Any(x => x.Type == "scope" && x.Value == "customScope") && result)
{
    foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have more elegant solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).